# Let $V$ be a NLS (over $\mathbb R$ ) of dimension $>1$, then for any $0 \le a < b$ , is the set $\{v \in V : a < ||v|| < b\}$ connected?

Tags: analysis, metric-spaces, normed-spaces, connectedness

Let $V$ be a normed linear space (over $\mathbb R$ ) , then for any $0 \le a < b$ , is the set $\{v \in V : a < ||v|| < b\}$ connected ? I know that if $V$ is the space of complex numbers $\mathbb C$ with usual norm then the set is connected  as it is nothing but the continuous image of the connected set $f:(1,2) \times [0, 2\pi) \to \mathbb C $ ; $(r,\theta ) \to re^{i\theta}$ ; but I cannot see this in general normed linear space . I think proving $\{v \in V :||v||=1 \}$ connected in $V$ will be enough as $\{v \in V : a < ||v|| < b\}$ is the continuous image of $f: (a,b) \times \{v \in V :||v||=1 \} \to V$ ; $f(r,v)=r.v$ . Please help . Thanks in advance

Comment: @ to all : is $V \setminus \{\theta \}$ connected in $V$ if $V$ has dimension more than $1$ ? I am thinking about the map $V \to \{v \in V :||v||=1 \}$ ; $v \to \dfrac v{||v||}$ then ....

Comment: The set is connected (and path-connected) if and only if the dimension is different from $1$.

Comment: @DanielFischer : Could you please give a proof ?

Comment: Try to prove it yourself. The important thing is that the sphere $S = \{ v\in V : \lVert v\rVert = 1\}$ is path-connected for $\dim_{\mathbb{R}} V > 1$. Try using your map to show that. What _could_ go wrong? Why can that be fixed if the situation arises for $\dim_{\mathbb{R}} V > 1$?

Comment: @DanielFischer : My knwoledge of the connectedness of $\mathbb R^n \setminus \{\theta \} $ is intuitive :Given $\vec x , \vec y$ different from null-vector , join them by the straight-line path between them if the path does not go through the origin ; otherwise choose a point $\vec z$ not on the line joining $\vec x , \vec y$ and take the broken path from $\vec x$ to $\vec z $ then $\vec z$ to $\vec y$ . But I don't know   whether this geometry will work for infinite dimensions ; so please help in writing down a formal proof

Comment: Yes, that's what one usually does. One must then project the path to the unit sphere. It works in finite [as long as the dimension is $> 1$] and in infinite dimension alike. The construction uses only a finite-dimensional subspace of $V$ for any fixed $x,y$, hence it is irrelevant how $V$ looks outside that finite-dimensional subspace. All you have to do is write it up, and say why the resulting map $[0,1] \to S \subset V$ is continuous (so it's a path connecting $x$ and $y$).